# How to fill the data into the datatable from variable list of data

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a little task, I want assign data to my combobox as datasource, display member, value member from SQL Server table of a single column, by using Linq-to-SQL.

I get the required data from table like

```
 var Uom = SpOpDcontx.Ptr_UOMs.Select(c => c.UM_Typ).Distinct().ToArray();
```

The data is being assigned to `Uom` variable, so I want to assign this data into my combobox datasource. Can any one help me please?

Comment: Side comment: We really need to work on your naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you mention a datatable when you don't use it and don't need it for this anyway. You simply need to do the following:

```
combo.DataSource = Uom;
combo.DisplayMember="UM_Typ";
combo.ValueMember="UM_Typ";
```

Comment: var Uom = SpOpDcontx.Ptr_UOMs.Select(c => c.UM_Typ).Distinct().ToArray();       this code i wrote in a separate class my combobox in a form,so how can access these data for my cbx.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use List?

```
 public class Test
    {
       // your all return properties goes here
       public string Typ;
    }

public class Test2
{
   public List<Test> GetRequireData()
   {
        var Uom = SpOpDcontx.Ptr_UOMs.Select(c => new Test()
                   {
                    Typ = c.UM_Typ)
                   })
                   .Distinct();
         return Uom.ToList<Test>();
   }
}
```

Now, you can call GetRequireData() in your form as;

```
var obj = new Test2();
combo.DisplayMember="UM_Typ";
combo.ValueMember="UM_Typ";
combo.DataSource = obj.GetRequireData();
```